# Reshaping datas in a specific form

Tags: r, reshape, data-munging

I've datas as follows, it is a but in reality i've few `experiment`, it is simplified dataset:

```
DF=structure(list(theoric = c("E", "E", "F", "F", "F"), observed = c("E", 
"E", "F", "F", "E"), experiment = c("RO(2)", "RO(2)", "RO(2)", "RO(2)", 
"RO(2)")), .Names = c("theoric", "observed", "experiment"), row.names = 2:6, class = "data.frame")
```

Now my datas has the following form:

```
  theoric observed  experiment
2       E        E RO(2)
3       E        E RO(2)
4       F        F RO(2)
5       F        F RO(2)
6       F        E RO(2)
```

Adn I want it to be reshaped as follows :

```
                  2 3 4 5 6
RO(2) theoric     E E F F F
RO(2) observed    E E F F E
```

What is the easiest way to do it ? I really have no idea how to do this. I tried

```
meltR <- melt(DF, id="experiment")
```

But i'm lost all correspondance between `theoric` and `observed`. Thanks a lot

EDIT : full dataset:

```
DF=structure(list(theoric = c("E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "E", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "E", "E", "E", "E"), observed = c("E", "E", 
"F", "F", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "E", "E", "E", "F"
), experiment = c("RO", "RO", "RO", "RO", "RO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "EL", "EL", "EL", "EL")), .Names = c("theoric", 
"observed", "experiment"), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 13L), class = "data.frame")
```

output:

```
    col2 col1.2 col1.3 col1.4 col1.5 col1.6 col1.24 col1.25 col1.26
1   RO theoric      E      E      F      F      F    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
6   MO theoric   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>       E       F       F
12  EL theoric   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
16 RO observed      E      E      F      F      E    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
21 MO observed   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>       F       F       F
27 EL observed   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
   col1.27 col1.28 col1.29 col1.21 col1.22 col1.23 col1.13
1     <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
6        F       F       F    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
12    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>       E       E       E       E
16    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
21       F       F       F    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
27    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>       E       E       E       F
```

EDIT 2 : Add `EL` ouput

```
RO theoric     E E F F F
RO observed    E E F F E
MO theoric     E F F F F
MO observed    F F F F F
EL theoric     E E E E
EL observed    E E E F
```

Comment: If you look at the input and output for the new dataset, it is clear that some numbers are only present for certain experiment.  So, I am not sure what you expect here

Comment: In your edit, the EL is not shown.  So, I think it is not correct output

Comment: You're right, apologies. Do you think it is ok like that ?

Comment: Some values are still not okay, Can you check my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the expected output, we may need to create a column with `row.names`.  Create a new dataset ('df2'), by `unlist`ing the first two columns, replicating the 'experiment' column, and a rownames column.  Then use `reshape` from `base R` to convert the 'long' format to 'wide'.

```
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = unlist(DF[1:2], use.names=FALSE), 
      col2 = paste( rep(DF$experiment, 2),
    rep(colnames(DF)[1:2], each = nrow(DF))), col3 = rep(row.names(DF), 2))

reshape(df2, idvar = "col2", direction="wide", timevar = "col3")
#             col2 col1.2 col1.3 col1.4 col1.5 col1.6
#1  RO(2) theoric      E      E      F      F      F
#6 RO(2) observed      E      E      F      F      E
```

---

Or using `melt/dcast` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' keeping the row names (`setDT(DF, keep.row.names = TRUE)`), `melt` it to 'long' format, `paste` the 'experiment' and 'variable' column, and then `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(DF, keep.rownames = TRUE), id.var = c("rn", "experiment"))[,
    experiment := paste(experiment, variable)], experiment~rn, value.var = "value")
#       experiment 2 3 4 5 6
#1: RO(2) observed E E F F E
#2:  RO(2) theoric E E F F F
```

#### Update

Using the new dataset,

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.7+
dcast(melt(setDT(DF), id.var = "experiment"), paste(experiment, 
    variable)~rowid(experiment, variable), value.var="value", fill="")
#    experiment 1 2 3 4 5 6
#1: EL observed E E E F    
#2:  EL theoric E E E E    
#3: MO observed F F F F F F
#4:  MO theoric E F F F F F
#5: RO observed E E F F E  
#6:  RO theoric E E F F F
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this complete answer, that works with the DF that I posted, but when I work with the full dataset that i've, it do not works, why ? see Edit. Thanks.

Comment: @ranell  I tested with the second solution using `dcast/melt` .  It does give output, but only thing is that all the combinations are not in your data, so it fills up with NA for those elements. i.e. 'MO' experiment have only row numbers 24:28, likewise, other experiment also have the same problem.

Comment: Rowid seems to be function of data.table. it returns me "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : impossible to found function "rowid"

Comment: @ranell It is in the devel version ie. 1.9.7.  If you are using `1.9.6`, then `dcast(melt(setDT(DF), id.var = "experiment")[, rid := 1:.N, .(experiment, variable)],  paste(experiment, 
    variable)~rid, value.var="value", fill="")`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience, it works correctly now :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the following:

```
require(tidyverse)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
DF %>% 
  gather(type, val, theoric, observed) %>% 
  unite(experiment, experiment, type, sep=" ") %>% 
  group_by(experiment) %>% 
  mutate(experiment_number = 1:n()) %>% 
  spread(experiment_number, val, fill="")
```

Which gives you:

```
   experiment   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`
*       <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 EL observed     E     E     E     F            
2  EL theoric     E     E     E     E            
3 MO observed     F     F     F     F     F     F
4  MO theoric     E     F     F     F     F     F
5 RO observed     E     E     F     F     E      
6  RO theoric     E     E     F     F     F
```